# Security issues when accepting user input image urls in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I want to allow users to upload urls for images (a bit like on this site in the markup). The only difference is that I'm going to store these in my database. I want to ensure nothing too malicious can be done.

After looking around I've seen the recommendation of `cURL` to check for the content_type as apparently `getimagesize()` actually downloads the full image, which not only has security implications (apparently - I'm really not an expert) but will therefore be slow.

So far my code is looking like this:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    if(curl_exec($curl)===FALSE)
    {
        curl_close($curl);
        return false;
    }

    $contentType = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);  //get content type
    curl_close( $curl );

    if (strpos($contentType, 'image')){
      // valid image
    }
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way to go about doing this. I've also seen lots about `sanitising` the urls, but not entirely sure what this would entail.

Any help on securing this part of my web app and preparing it for storage would be highly appreciated.

As a quick aside, I'm hoping to do the same for YouTube links so if you have any recommendations for that, I'd appreciate it - though I've not begun research into this yet.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can also escape special chars and what not using the function below

```html
<?php
  $url = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST["inputName"]));
?>
```

This will add splashes and turn & signs to html entities https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp instead so you might need to reverse this process when reading the data from the database.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is completely inappropriate here -- this question has nothing to do with inserting URLs into a database, and even if it did, `htmlspecialchars` does not escape strings for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to allow users to upload a file by URL, start by downloading the file (either by using cURL, or any other tools you like). Don't bother making an initial request to check the Content-Type -- what matters is ultimately the *content* of the file, not the headers it happens to served with by the original server.

Once you've downloaded the image, perform any further checks on the local file. Make sure it is an appropriate format, and is not too large, then convert it to your preferred format.

Other notes:

- Don't use a fake User-Agent. Use an accurate one which represents what web site is responsible for the request, e.g. `"MySite/1.0 http://example.com/"`. (Other webmasters will thank you for this!)
- It's a good idea to do a DNS lookup on the domain before requesting it, to protect your server from [DNS rebinding attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding). Make sure that the resulting IP does not point to your private network, or to localhost, before you make an HTTP request.